# Trying to obtain memberof detail from linux ldapsearch command

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am trying run an LDAP query from a Linux machine (CentOS 5.8) to a Windows LDAP server and want to get 'memberof' detail for a user. In this example, the  Domain is cm.loc and the user is admin1@cm.loc. Here is the ldapsearch syntax I am using. It returns an error.
Can someone point me in the right direction with what the correct syntax should be using ldapsearch to query for memberof detail for a particular account?

Here is what I am using that returns error;  "ldap search ext bad search filter 7"
Where is my syntax wrong?

```
ldapsearch –x –h 192.168.1.20 –b 'DC=cm,DC=loc' -s base –D 'admin1@cm.loc' -W '(&(objectCategory=Group)(|(memberOf=group1)(memberOf=group2)…))'
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax looks OK, you need to use the full DN syntax for the `memberOf` query, and it's still `memberOf=`, not `memberOf:` - if you use the colon syntax then you'll get the bad search filter error.

The next thing is that you *must* escape the search string according to the specifications of RFC4515. This generally means that the following characters in the search string terms: `\`, `*`, `(`, and `)` must be escaped using `\5c`, `\2a`, `\28`, `\29` respectively, otherwise you get the same error - bad search term. This is ***on top of*** the escaping that the ldap server may have applied to the DN already.

Answer (score 1):

`memberOf` is an attribute with `DN` syntax. `group1` is not a DN.

Comment: I tried modifying syntax to include DN format for memberof as follows: ldapsearch –x –h 192.168.1.20 –b 'DC=cm,DC=loc' -s base –D 'admin1@cm.loc' -W '(&(objectCategory=Group)(|(memberOf: CN=admin1,DC=cm,DC=loc))' and still receive error failure of ldap_search_ext bad search filter (-7) –

Comment: Use memberOf= not memberOf: